# d3fc/d3.js How to stack multiple discontinuities

Tags: d3.js, d3fc

I've been trying to create a scale with multiple breaks using d3fc/d3.js. For example this is how i am trying to currently create a scale from 0 to 100 with a break from 10 to 20 and 50 to 80:

```
 var scale = fc.scaleDiscontinuous(d3.scaleLinear());
 breaks = [[10,20],[50,80]];

 for (break_index in breaks){

    b = breaks[break_index];
    scale.discontinuityProvider(fc.discontinuityRange(b));

 }


scale.domain([ 100, 0])
     .range([content_width,0]);
```

This however only returns a scale with a break from 50-80 meaning the first break (10-20) is being overwritten. Is there any way to have multiple breaks in the same scale?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is iterating over the `breaks` array and setting the `discontinuityProvider` property on each iteration. Each time you set this property, you override the previous value!

The solution is to provide multiple 'breaks' directly to the discontinuity provider:

```
const scale = fc.scaleDiscontinuous(d3.scaleLinear());
  .discontinuityProvider(fc.discontinuityRange([10,20], [50,80]))
  .domain([ 100, 0])
  .range([content_width,0]);
```

Comment: In the event you must pass a multi dimensional array, can also use `.apply` method. where `let multi_arr=[[10,20],[50,80]]` is passed to  `fc.discontinuityRange.apply(fc.discontinuityRange, multi_arr);`